# For a better understanding of $i_*$ using an example

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$ be a smooth projective surface in $\mathbb{P}^3$ containing a line $l$.
Denote by $C$ the curve corresponding to the divisor $2l$. Let $p \in C$ be a closed point. Denote by $U:=C \backslash p$ and $i:U \hookrightarrow C$, the natural immersion. What is the stalk $i_*(\mathcal{O}_U)_p$?